# UserPool.getCurrentUser( ) returns null [backend]

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

Am trying to set up a federated identity in order to get credentials for identity. But when i try to do the **getCurrentUser()** am getting response as null. And another thing about this is, am trying this on **backend side**. So will it work in the backend? And why am getting a null response when trying getCurrentUser ?? Any idea?

```
var data = {
    UserPoolId: userPoolId,
    ClientId: appClientId,
  };

var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(data);
console.log(userPool);
var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
console.log(cognitoUser);
```

The log response of **userPool** is

```
CognitoUserPool {
    userPoolId: 'us-east-6_hxxxx2U',
    clientId: '`6heh4h8h848h4884h05',
    client:
     Client {
       endpoint: 'https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/',
       userAgent: 'aws-amplify/0.1.x js' },
    advancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag: true,
    storage:
     { [Function: MemoryStorage]
       setItem: [Function: setItem],
       getItem: [Function: getItem],
       removeItem: [Function: removeItem],
       clear: [Function: clear] } }
```

The log response of cognitoUser is `NULL`

So why is response null, while am giving right values as input?

Answer (score 1):

There are few potential causes:

1. Use `getCurrentUser()` instead of `getCurrentUser(Data)`
2. If you didn’t sign in a user at backend, it wouldn’t be possible to get the current user. If users are signed in at front end, you can use a function to send user’s id_token to backend and use it to sign in the use at backend.

About the second point:

The id_token contains a part called payload which contains the user’s username and other attributes. For details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-id-token

When you use the id_token you should verify the signature before allowing further actions for the user. Codes for verifying can be found in https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/tree/master/Cognito/decode-verify-jwt 
And you can add you code for actions here:

```
                    .....
                    // and the Audience (use claims.client_id if verifying an access token)

                    if (claims.aud != app_client_id) {

                        callback('Token was not issued for this audience');

                    }

                    //add your code here

                    callback(null, claims);

                }).

                catch(function() {

                    callback('Signature verification failed');

                });
```

And the user information should be in the `claims`.

Comment: So how could i sign in the user at backend? Can you specify what function to use ?

Comment: Does user login from front end?

Comment: No. I pass the token to frontend. Thats it!

Comment: Are you using Cognito hosted ui?

Comment: No. Am using admin_srp_auth inorder to login user from backend. Can you just explain the 2nd point you have written on answer??

Answer (score 0):

Its because the code I have posted here is for the frontend. There is an article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html which says clearly how should we try to authenticate a user.

So after the correct auth flow, we will pass the required data by using  `cognitoidentity.getCredentialsForIdentity()`   [refer offical sdk doc]