# Error: User is not authenticated amazon cognito in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using `amazon-Cognito-identity-js` and `aws-sdk` to setup authentication in my nodeJs app.

### What i did

First i signup using `userpool.signUp(..)` method according to [docs](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js).
Then i confirmed the verification code using `cognitoUser.confirmRegistration(..)` method according to [docs](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js).

Up to here, everything works fine. But, now i would like to get all attributes of the user. I found a method `cognitoUser.getUserAttributes(..)` which can give me attributes. But when i call this method after `cognitoUser.confirmRegistration(..)` then it returns **Error: User is not authenticated**.

> I went through a SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049865/userpool-getcurrentuser-returns-null-backend) where I got `getCurrentUser()` will return null at backend side.

So, how can I authorize any user at the fully secured backend side using nodejs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to first call the `authenticateUser` method:

```
import { CognitoUser, AuthenticationDetails } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'

const authUser = () => {
  const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({ Username, Pool })
  const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
    Username,
    Password,
  })
  cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      console.log("User authenticated")
    },
    onFailure: (error) => {
      console.log("An error happened")
    },
  })
}
```

After that, the `getCurrentUser` method will return the current logged in user. And you will be able to call the `getUserAttributes` method as well.